# The Command **** exited with Code 1

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I inherited a project and when I try to build it I'm getting the below errors but don't know where to look to find the command it's trying to run.

```
> Error 2   The command
> ""C:\TFS_Source_GIS\Hydrology\HydrologicApplication\IDWR.Hydrologic.HydrologicApplication\.nuget\nuget.exe"> install> "C:\TFS_Source_GIS\Hydrology\HydrologicApplication\IDWR.Hydrologic.HydrologicApplication\IDWR.Hydrologic.HydrologicApplication\packages.config"
> -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\TFS_Source_GIS\Hydrology\HydrologicApplication\IDWR.Hydrologic.HydrologicApplication\
> "" exited with code 1.    IDWR.Hydrologic.HydrologicApplication
> 
> Error 1   Unknown option: '-solutionDir'  IDWR.Hydrologic.HydrologicApplication
```

I would have thought it's be in my project file but it's not.  Below is my project file.

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
> DefaultTargets="Build"
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">  
> <PropertyGroup>
>     <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
>     <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
>     <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
>     <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
>     <ProjectGuid>{48DDAE38-C57E-4E15-8F6D-BA138C234F9D}</ProjectGuid>
>     <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
>     <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
>     <RootNamespace>IDWR.Hydrologic.HydrologicApplication</RootNamespace>
>     <AssemblyName>IDWR.Hydrologic.HydrologicApplication</AssemblyName>
>     <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
>     <TargetFrameworkProfile>
>     </TargetFrameworkProfile>
>     <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
>     <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
>     <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
>     <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
>     <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
>     <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
>     <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>   </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
>     <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
>     <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
>     <DebugType>full</DebugType>
>     <Optimize>false</Optimize>
>     <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
>     <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
>     <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
>     <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>   </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
>     <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
>     <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
>     <Optimize>true</Optimize>
>     <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
>     <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
>     <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
>     <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>   </PropertyGroup>   <ItemGroup>
>     <Reference Include="DotSpatial.Projections">
>       <HintPath>..\packages\DotSpatial.Projections.1.4.17\lib\net40-Client\DotSpatial.Projections.dll</HintPath>
>     </Reference>
>     <Reference Include="DotSpatial.Projections.Forms">
>       <HintPath>..\packages\DotSpatial.Projections.1.4.17\lib\net40-Client\DotSpatial.Projections.Forms.dll</HintPath>
>     </Reference>
>     <Reference Include="log4net">
>       <HintPath>..\packages\log4net.2.0.0\lib\net40-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
>     </Reference>
>     <Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL">
>       <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
>       <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll</HintPath>
>     </Reference>
>     <Reference Include="System" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Core" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Transactions" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
>     <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Data" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
>     <Reference Include="WREdit.Launcher">
>       <HintPath>..\packages\WREditLauncher.Core.2.0.1852.1\lib\net40\WREdit.Launcher.dll</HintPath>
>     </Reference>   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
>     <Compile Include="AddReturnFlowForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="AddReturnFlowForm.designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>AddReturnFlowForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="AddSiteForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="AddSiteForm.designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>AddSiteForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="AddSWRawFromFile.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="AddSWRawFromFile.designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>AddSWRawFromFile.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="AddSWTimeSeriesForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="AddSWTimeSeriesForm.designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>AddSWTimeSeriesForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="DisplaySiteInfoForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="DisplaySiteInfoForm.designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>DisplaySiteInfoForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="EditHydrologicForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="EditHydrologicForm.Designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>EditHydrologicForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="GlobalUtilityClass.cs" />
>     <Compile Include="HydrologicDataSet.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>HydrologicDataSet.xsd</DependentUpon>
>       <SubType>Component</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="HydrologicDataSet.Designer.cs">
>       <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
>       <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
>       <DependentUpon>HydrologicDataSet.xsd</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="ManageHydrologicForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="ManageHydrologicForm.Designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>ManageHydrologicForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
>     <Compile Include="Projections.cs" />
>     <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
>     <Compile Include="RadiusBufferSiteSearchForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="RadiusBufferSiteSearchForm.Designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>RadiusBufferSiteSearchForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="ReturnFlowChartForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="ReturnFlowChartForm.designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>ReturnFlowChartForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="SelectMeasurementMethodandMonitoringAgencyForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="SelectMeasurementMethodandMonitoringAgencyForm.designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>SelectMeasurementMethodandMonitoringAgencyForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="SelectSiteForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="SelectSiteForm.designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>SelectSiteForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="StartForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="StartForm.designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>StartForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="SWTimeSeriesChartForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="SWTimeSeriesChartForm.designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>SWTimeSeriesChartForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="TableAdapters.TransactionSupport.cs">
>       <SubType>Component</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="TimeSeriesForm.cs">
>       <SubType>Form</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="TimeSeriesForm.Designer.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>TimeSeriesForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="AddReturnFlowForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>AddReturnFlowForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="AddSiteForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>AddSiteForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="AddSWRawFromFile.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>AddSWRawFromFile.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="AddSWTimeSeriesForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>AddSWTimeSeriesForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="DisplaySiteInfoForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>DisplaySiteInfoForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="EditHydrologicForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>EditHydrologicForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="ManageHydrologicForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>ManageHydrologicForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
>       <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
>       <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
>       <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
>       <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
>       <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
>     </Compile>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="RadiusBufferSiteSearchForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>RadiusBufferSiteSearchForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="ReturnFlowChartForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>ReturnFlowChartForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="SelectMeasurementMethodandMonitoringAgencyForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>SelectMeasurementMethodandMonitoringAgencyForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="SelectSiteForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>SelectSiteForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="StartForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>StartForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="SWTimeSeriesChartForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>SWTimeSeriesChartForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <EmbeddedResource Include="TimeSeriesForm.resx">
>       <DependentUpon>TimeSeriesForm.cs</DependentUpon>
>     </EmbeddedResource>
>     <None Include="app.config" />
>     <None Include="HydrologicDataSet.xsc">
>       <DependentUpon>HydrologicDataSet.xsd</DependentUpon>
>     </None>
>     <None Include="HydrologicDataSet.xsd">
>       <Generator>MSDataSetGenerator</Generator>
>       <LastGenOutput>HydrologicDataSet.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </None>
>     <None Include="HydrologicDataSet.xss">
>       <DependentUpon>HydrologicDataSet.xsd</DependentUpon>
>     </None>
>     <None Include="log4net.config" />
>     <None Include="packages.config">
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </None>
>     <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
>       <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
>       <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
>     </None>
>     <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
>       <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
>       <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
>       <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
>     </Compile>   </ItemGroup>   <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />   <Import
> Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />   <!-- To modify your
> build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and
> uncomment it. 
>        Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.   <Target Name="BeforeBuild">   </Target>  
> <Target Name="AfterBuild">   </Target>   --> </Project>
```

Where else could it be?

Comment: The command is from the nuget.targets file. NuGet.exe supports the -SolutionDir option so not sure why there is an error about it unless your NuGet.exe is an old version. I would try running the command from the command line and see if it has the same error.

Comment: That was it.  Nuget.exe was an older version.   Replaced it with a newer version and it all worked.  Thank you.